# Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels

Tags: python, django, pip, pythonanywhere

I was using a virtualenv in Pythonanywhere and now after cloning my repo I tried to install all the packages by using this command

```
pip install -r packageName/requrirements.txt
```

What is get is this

```
Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels
```

I don't know about pip a lot.So please tell me what this eror means and how can i fix it with examples!Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show your `requrirements.txt`.

Comment: also can you show the full error stacktrace? ie. there is possibly more hints in the full error

Answer (score 0):

PythonAnywhere's web bash console is a bit buggy: it has not correctly pasted the content for me and caused the same message as for you. If you are using the web bash shell, check your requirements.txt file content if it is there, and if there are some special characters entered.

Comment: What do you mean by "buggy"?  Is this related to the fact that you wanted to paste special characters into it?

Comment: I was using vi on bash console, 'vi requirements.txt' and then pressed 'i' for insert in vi, and pasted content to the editor. It has shown the text in the vi window, and so I pressed ESC, :, qw to save the file in vi, but still I got an empty file.